# Does Ubuntu Like my PC's Drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, windows, windows-10

I don't know much about Ubuntu other than it's Linux and I'm fed up with Microsoft (I'm currently running windows). So I don't know weather Ubuntu works with my PC drivers.

Here they are: 
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB as my display 
8 Core Intel CPU i7-4770 @ 3.4GHz 
Those are all I can find that I feel would make an impact.

Comment: Nothing unusual so it most work fine. Nvidia will need proprietary drivers for better performance but currently those can be automatically installed when the related option is selected during Ubuntu installation. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu installer includes a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can test your hardware with Ubuntu BEFORE committing to an install. Test your video card, your audio, your wireless, your printer, and everything else. If something critical doesn't work properly, then don't install Ubuntu.

No, your Windows drivers won't work on Ubuntu. But that's usually not relevant for most hardware -- the Linux kernel contains compatibility modules for most hardware.